# Cannot read property 'toObject' of undefined when trying to call a func property

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs

This is my component

```
class MyComponent  extends Component {
  render () {
    const { action } = this.props;
    action();
    return (<div>Done!</div>);
  }

MyComponent.propTypes = {
   action: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

And here is the relevant code of a container:

```
   doSomething () {  
     ...
   }
   render() {
      return (
        <MyComponent
         action={doSomething}
        />
      )
   }
```

When I bring up this code in a browser, I got this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toObject' of undefined
```

Business logic should live in container so I do not want to copy and paste the code of `action` into `MyComponent`.

So my question is: how can I call a function passed in via properties directly in a `render` method?

Comment: pls show the code of `action`. the error seems to occur inside `action` which means `action` gets called.

Comment: I think it's not generally good idea to call a function (that doesn't really returns you something to render) inside the `render` function. I'd probably do it in `componentWillUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle methods. Would be better if you could share what does the `action` function do.

Comment: @Ved how action is `this.props`, he is using `{action}=this.props`, that is called `destructuring`, that syntax is proper.

Comment: @Panther You're right. The exception is thrown from within the `action` function. It wasn't obvious from the stacktrace until I put a debugger statement inside the function. Please make your comment an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @MayankShukla You are correct. I thought destructuring is only supported in ES7. so,.

Comment: @AnthonyKong, Thanks. Glad to help. Thats all we expect each other to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think, issue is in this place:

```
doSomething () {  
     ...
}

render() {
   return (
     <MyComponent
        action={doSomething}  //here
     />
   )
}
```

It should be:

```
doSomething () {  
   ...
}

render() {
   return (
      <MyComponent
         action={this.doSomething}
      />
   )
}
```

You need to use `this.doSomething` instead of `doSomething`.

Check the working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

   constructor(){
      super();
   }
   
   doSomething(){
       console.log('called');
   }
   
   render(){
       return(
          <div>
             Hello
             <Child action={this.doSomething}/>
          </div>
       )
   }
}

var Child = (props) => {
   const {action} = props
   action();
   return(
     <div>Child</div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```